# Magento get language collection

Tags: zend-framework, magento, enterprise

There seems to be a possibility in Magento to get a language collection, namely via `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_language')`, which I would like to use. It results however in an error in my version of Magento (both Enterprise 1.10 and Community 1.4), expecting to get its data from an unexisting table called core_language.

Has anyone found a good solution or alternative to this? Or maybe have used this and has a table dump for core_language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento is built on [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.functions.html) so you can use,

```
Zend_Locale::getTranslationList("language")
```

which returns an array of strings keyed by their abbreviation.

Comment: As a small improvement to this: ``Zend_Locale::getLanguageTranslationList`` seems to be deprecated as well. I think the call should be ``Zend_Locale::getTranslationList("language")``.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I looked through the installation files and apparently the table is created initially but dropped from version 0.7.5, so it's probably deprecated code. The class file doesn't mention this though, so quite obscure.